# Android ParseObject java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android

I am using ParseObject for Saving Devise id for Push Notification. Here is My Code

```
ParseObject Object = new ParseObject("Key");
TelephonyManager tManager = 
    (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
devicetoken = tManager.getDeviceId();

Object.put("user_objectId", "user_"+devicetoken);
Object.saveInBackground();
```

But I am getting this error.

```
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196): Process: com.codenterprise.CashbackKorting, PID: 25196
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196): java.lang.VerifyError: com/parse/ParseACL
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at com.parse.ParseObject.setDefaultValues(ParseObject.java:2764)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:160)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at com.codenterprise.CashbackKorting.Tab.onCreate(Tab.java:111)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-25 13:10:21.770: E/AndroidRuntime(25196):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you please help me identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the following code to your application startup (usually in Application.onCreate()):

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();  //.If you don't use a custom sign-up method


ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
// Optionally enable public read access while disabling public write access.
// defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

Anyway, `java.lang.VerifyError` is thrown when the "verifier" detects that a class file, though well formed, contains some sort of internal inconsistency or security problem.

This exception could be the result when "*you*" have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime. Try to check all the libraries (.jar) in your `libs` path are the latest versions. For example, if you are using only Parse, try to check if is the latest release, or if you are using others libraries that are build upon Parse, check if they use the same release.

Comment: Now giving same error on this line ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

Comment: i was using parse-1.3.0.jar. upon your suggestion i have updated my jar to latest version but issue still remains.

Comment: after updated the library, did you clean all the project and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, i followed these steps as well.

Comment: i Just Noticed i have jar for newRelic. if i removed that than it works fine but without newRelic jar ican't configure newRelic.

Comment: Ok, I don't know newRelic, but as usual, try to update to the latest release of library